# How do I wire in this replacement ceiling fan remote receiver?

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

I bought a Hunter universal remote set to replace the ceiling fan/light remote.

The old receiver has "to Motor L" and to "Motor N" while the new one only has one wire for the fan.

Is there a way to make it work?

[image: old receiver]
<sup>Click images to embiggen</sup>

[image: hunter receiver]

Answer (score 1):

The one "To motor" is the speed-controlled live. It replaces "To motor L"

The other motor lead previously served by "To motor N" goes to the regular neutral wire.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just to clarify, so I should connect the "Fan" to the "Motor L" and the other motor lead to the white wire beside the black live wire? Thanks

Comment: I already installed as instructed and works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: yeah the fan is the bit that moves the air the motor is the bit that moves the fan, and the electricity is the bit that moves the motor :)